# Change URL back after decode

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, urldecode

ive the following URL and I use decode to remove the %3AF%2 etc

```
http%3AF%2Fmo-d6fa3.ao.tzp.corp%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=x2.node";
```

for that I use `var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(url)`

I did some changes to this and my question is how should I return it back to the original format (as I posted). I try with encode which doesnt work...

Comment: Did you try encodeURIComponent() ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'encode doesn't work'? encodeURIComponent does exactly that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `encodeURIComponent()` to encode it again.

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/q9dtcry4/

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var uri = "http:F/mo-d6fa3.ao.tzp.corp:3000/login/callback&client_id=x2.node";
    var uri_enc = encodeURIComponent(uri);
    var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri_enc);
    var res = "Encoded URI: " + uri_enc + "<br>" + "Decoded URI: " + uri_dec;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

**Output:**

```
Encoded URI: http%3AF%2Fmo-d6fa3.ao.tzp.corp%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fcallback%26client_id%3Dx2.node
Decoded URI: http:F/mo-d6fa3.ao.tzp.corp:3000/login/callback&client_id=x2.node
```